# HTML Canvas fill with diagonal lines

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Good Evening, I'm working on a project where I need to create MSPaint clone, with one little functionality more. It must have a function that works almost like fill (bucket) but filling area matching pixels with diagonal lines (picture below) instead of filling all of them.

[image: shape filled with diagonal lines]

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/Kamskyy/pen/eYrRxRB

Below is my working function code for filling - how can I modify it to draw diagonal lines instead?

```js
function actionFill(startX,startY,currentColor) {
    //get imageData
    let colorLayer = offScreenCTX.getImageData(0, 0, offScreenCVS.width, offScreenCVS.height);

    let startPos = (startY*offScreenCVS.width + startX) * 4;

    //clicked color
    let startR = colorLayer.data[startPos]; 
    let startG = colorLayer.data[startPos+1];   
    let startB = colorLayer.data[startPos+2];
    let startA = colorLayer.data[startPos+3];
    
    //exit if color is the same
    if (currentColor.r === startR && currentColor.g === startG && currentColor.b === startB && currentColor.a === startA) {
        return;
    }
    //Start with click coords
    let pixelStack = [[startX,startY]];
    let newPos, x, y, pixelPos, reachLeft, reachRight;
    floodFill();
    function floodFill() {
        newPos = pixelStack.pop();
        x = newPos[0];
        y = newPos[1];

        //get current pixel position
        pixelPos = (y*offScreenCVS.width + x) * 4;
        // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
        while(y >= 0 && matchStartColor(pixelPos)) {
            y--;
            pixelPos -= offScreenCVS.width * 4;
        }
        //Don't overextend
        pixelPos += offScreenCVS.width * 4;
        y++;
        reachLeft = false;
        reachRight = false;
        // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
        while(y < offScreenCVS.height && matchStartColor(pixelPos)) {
            
            colorPixel(pixelPos);

            if(x > 0) {
                if(matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4)) {
                    if(!reachLeft) {
                        //Add pixel to stack
                        pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                        reachLeft = true;
                    }
                } else if(reachLeft) {
                    reachLeft = false;
                }
            }
        
            if(x < offScreenCVS.width-1) {
                if(matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4)) {
                    if(!reachRight) {
                        //Add pixel to stack
                        pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                        reachRight = true;
                    }
                } else if(reachRight) {
                    reachRight = false;
                }
            }
            y++;        
            pixelPos += offScreenCVS.width * 4;
        }
        
        if (pixelStack.length) {
            floodFill();
            // window.setTimeout(floodFill, 100);
        }
    }

    //render floodFill result
    offScreenCTX.putImageData(colorLayer, 0, 0);

    //helpers
    function matchStartColor(pixelPos) {
        let r = colorLayer.data[pixelPos];  
        let g = colorLayer.data[pixelPos+1];    
        let b = colorLayer.data[pixelPos+2];
        let a = colorLayer.data[pixelPos+3];
        return (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB && a === startA);
    }

    function colorPixel(pixelPos) {
        colorLayer.data[pixelPos] = currentColor.r;
        colorLayer.data[pixelPos+1] = currentColor.g;
        colorLayer.data[pixelPos+2] = currentColor.b;
        //not ideal
        colorLayer.data[pixelPos+3] = currentColor.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Maybe you can flood fill using unique color then replace that color with red or white according to position x,y

Comment: This works only for rectangles. I need it to fill with hatches all kinds of shapes

Comment: I will create minial reproducible example.

Comment: Here it is https://codepen.io/Kamskyy/full/eYrRxRB

Comment: The answer on the linked question does work with any shape, as long as you're able to "trace“ it using the context methods like `lineTo()`, `arc()` etc. Are you able to do so or not? How is determined your original "shape to fill"?